# Can someone explain what the pseudo-code below is trying to do?

Tags: arrays, pseudocode

Below is the pseudo-code. In my opinion, it is the pseudo-code is trying to find the peak elements along with their index in a list of tuples.

The output on my end is : [(1, 4), (4, -9), (7, 12), (9, -4)].

But I do not know how `(9, -4)` can be the answer?

```
array[N] # array of N integers, indexed 0 to N-1;
# assume it’s populated with [1,4,2,-2,-9,10,2,12,2,-4,-4,-4,-4,2,6,7]
peak = array[0]
index = 0
output = [] # array of tuples
For x in 1..N-1
    if (array[x]*array[x-1] > 0)
       if peak < 0 and array[x] < peak
          peak = array[x]
          index = x
       if peak >= 0 and array[x] > peak
          peak = array[x]
          index = x

    else
       output.insert( (index, peak) )
       peak = array[x]
       index = x
end if
end for
return output
```

Comment: If it's pseudo code it's not python, don't spam tags please.

Comment: @Julien Apologies. Can you help here?

Comment: this code finds all local extrema (at the first index encountered), (9,-4) is one of them.

Comment: @Julien so can -4 be considered as a peak value as the successor value (-4) is the same? It should be greater right?

Answer (score 0):

> the pseudo-code is trying to find the peak elements along with their index in a list of tuples

It may look like that, but this is not actually happening. The example input has other local extremes that are not in the output. If we define a local extreme (peak) as any element in the array that is not surrounded by both a greater and lesser value, then the example input would have these local extremes:

```
[1, 4, 2, -2, -9, 10, 2, 12, 2, -4, -4, -4, -4, 2, 6, 7]
 ^  ^          ^  ^   ^  ^       ^   ^   ^   ^        ^
```

We could have different definitions that would exclude the very first and last element, or that would exclude a sequence of duplicate values, but still the values 10, 2 and 12 would be regarded local extremes, and yet this pseudo code will not output those.

The pseudo code will output a pair when the **sign** changes when going from one value to the next: the pair that is then output will represent the peak in the previous section of same-signed numbers. Since in your example input the sign changes 4 times, it is expected that there are 4 pairs in the output. Also, if the input consists of only negative numbers or of only strictly positive numbers, the output will be empty.

The change of sign includes cases where a zero is involved. Also, the algorithm will **never** include the last element in the output, but can include the first element. It does not always give mirrored output when you mirror the input. It does not always give the same number of peaks when you just add a constant to all array values (because that may alter the sign of the numbers).

So for instance, we get these outputs:

| input | output |
| --- | --- |
| `[0,0,0,0]` | `[(0,0),(1,0),(2,0)]` |
| `[1,1,1,1]` | `[]` |
| `[-1,0,1,2]` | `[(0,-1),(1,0)]` |
| `[2,1,0,-1]` | `[(0,2),(2,0)]` |
| `[0,1,0,1]` | `[(0,0),(1,1),(2,0)]` |
| `[1,2,1]` | `[]` |
| `[-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3]` | `[(0,-3),(3,0),(6,3),(9,0)]` |
| `[1,2,3,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,3,2,1]` | `[]` |

I don't see a practical use for this algorithm, and wonder if it actually does what the author intended it to do.